# MapStruct: How to update a bean reference instead properties values

Tags: mapstruct

Folks,

I have the following situation with MapStruct: I want to always update a field with a new instance instead of setting values in a pre-existing instance.

Example:

```
class A {
     B fieldB;
}

class B {
     String fieldString;
}

class ADTO {
     BDTO fieldB;
}

class BDTO {
     String fieldString;
}
```

I have the following mapping with MapStruct:

```
void copy(ADTO aDTO, @MappingTarget A a);
```

The result generated is similar to:

```
if (aDTO.getFieldB()!= null) {
    if (a.getFieldB() == null) {
        a.setFieldB(new B());
    }
    bDTOToB(aDTO.getFieldB(), a.getFieldB());
} else {
    a.setFieldB(null);
}
```

What I would like to generate is the following:

```
if (aDTO.getFieldB()!= null) {
    a.setFieldB(new B());  // ALWAYS create a new B instance
    bDTOToB(aDTO.getFieldB(), a.getFieldB());
} else {
    a.setFieldB(null);
}
```

I add that I need the 2 behaviors: for some fields the current behavior suits me, that is, set the values in an existing instance. For other fields, I need this change in behavior as I mentioned before (`a.setFieldB(newB())`).

Is it possible to do that? What better strategy?

Comment: How do you distinguish the fields that should be cleared from the ones that shouldn't? Your requiremement seems quite original, can you provide some business context?

Comment: Scenario: I use Spring MVC + Thymeleaf to render html pages, in addition, I also use Hibernate / JPA to persist data in the database.
In this scenario I have a page to edit a certain entity ("class A"). On this screen, it is possible to change a field that references another entity ("A.fieldB"). This page sends the data to a DTO ("class ADTO"), which I later convert to the class mapped with Hibernate ("class A"). When doing this conversion from "class ADTO" to "class A", I CANNOT set the "A.fieldB.id" since Hibernate does NOT allow this.

Comment: Continueing...

So, instead of setting the "class B" fields, I would simply have to create a new "class B" instance with the new id. That way, when persisting "class A", Hibernate will understand that "fieldB" has been changed and save that change in the database. That is, I want to change the reference of fieldB, but I do NOT want to change the data of an existing "class B" instance. Did you understand?

Answer (score 3):

The only way this is possible is like this:

```java
    @BeforeMapping
    default void init( @MappingTarget A a ) {
        a.setFieldB( new B() );
    }

    void copy(ADTO aDTO, @MappingTarget A a);
```

The `@BeforeMapping` will set your field prior to check. It will however **not** ommit the (now obsolete) null check on the target in the generated code.

There's no way to control the target check in MapStruct. The `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` defines how a null source should be handled in the target.

Comment: It's possible to receive Source and Target objects in Before/After mapping method?

Comment: @MarlonPatrick why not just try it?

I'll only add that you can also clear the field with `a.setFieldB(null)`. in `@BeforeMapping`

Comment: Yes it is possible to add source and also context parameters. Checkout the documentation on the mapstruct site. Was your question answered?